# AVCaptureSessionPresetLow on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, opentok

I'm a n00b to AVCaptureSession. I'm using OpenTok to implement video chat. I want to preserve bandwidth and the UI is designed so the video views are only 100 x 100 presently.

This is part of the code from an OpenTok example where it sets the preset:

```
- (void) setCaptureSessionPreset:(NSString*)preset {
AVCaptureSession *session = [self captureSession];

if ([session canSetSessionPreset:preset] &&
    ![preset isEqualToString:session.sessionPreset]) {

    [_captureSession beginConfiguration];
    _captureSession.sessionPreset = preset;
    _capturePreset = preset;

    [_videoOutput setVideoSettings:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:
       kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange],
      kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
      nil]];

    [_captureSession commitConfiguration];
}
```

}

When I pass in `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow` (on an iPhone 6) I get `NO`. Is there any way I can set AVCaptureSession so I can only capture video with a frame as close to 100 x 100 as possible?

Also, is this the correct strategy for trying to save bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force the camera to a resolution it does not support.
A lower resolution frame size will lead to lower network traffic. 
Lowering FPS is one other way.

A view size does not have to map to a resolution. You can always fit a frame in any size view.

Look at the Let-Build-OTPublisher app in OpenTok SDK and more specifically TBExampleVideoCapture.m file, on how resolution and FPS are handled.

Comment: "A lower resolution frame size will lead to lower network traffic." - So are you suggesting I just capture with the lowest preset available but then I can post-process it into a smaller frame before sending? I've been looking at TBExampleVideoCapture.m but I'm new to the AVCaptureSession framework so just looking for a little guidance.